# OS-wide synchronized access to MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, shared-memory, synchronize

I can have 2 Java processes share a region of memory via `MappedByteBuffer`.

But if these 2 processes can simultaneously read from or write to a byte at offset `x` (from start of the shared memory), how do I synchronize access to this byte?

Here's the **desired** usage:

*Assumption: There's only 1 thread per process that will attempt the read-write access.*

```
                           |
========================== | ============================
     Process A             |         Process B
========================== | ============================
                           |
lock(sharedMemory[x]);     |    lock(sharedMemory[x]);      (Line 1.)
  ...                      |      ...
// read from byte at x     |    // write to byte at x
a = sharedMemory[x];       |    sharedMemory[x] = b;
  ...                      |      ...
unlock(sharedMemory[x]);   |    unlock(sharedMemory[x]);    (Line 20.)
========================== | ============================
                           |
```

*Time flows downward in the above diagram.*

So, only process A or process B (but never both) can be executing Lines 1 through 20 at a given time.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to reimplement IPC, effectively. Operating systems have provided a variety of useful mechanisms for IPC over the years, some of which do not suffer from this problem. Are you sure you need to reinvent the wheel here?

Comment: One very important keyword in my question: **Java**.

Comment: Yes, Java can call native libraries. Java also supports that well-known IPC mechanism, TCP/IP sockets.

Comment: You could use a FileLock: exclusive lock for writing, and shared lock for reading.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen Hmm, now why didn't I think of that?! :-) Please consider posting your comment as an answer. I'll evaluate it relative to Peter's, and will choose the simpler alternative (after a few days). Thanks!

Comment: @SamiKorhonen, Can I used `MappedByteBuffer` along with `FileLock` (against the same backing file)? Meaning, synchronizing using `FileLock` but using `MappedByteBuffer` for its file mapping abstraction benefits?

Comment: Not quite sure, but it's obviously something that is easy to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way of doing this in Java. What you can try doing is use Unsafe, to create your own lock as I do in this library [AbstractByte in OpenHFT/Java-Lang](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/io/AbstractBytes.java) see the tryLock, busyLock, unlock methods.

I haven't test how well this works across processes. At present I only have a single process writing.

If you have one writer and one reader, you don't need to lock the record. You can use a memory barrier or a timestamp guard.

A simple timestamp guard can work like this.

Writer:

```
- on start, 
    - if even, increment to odd with memory barriers.
    - if odd, retry until even.
- perform multiple writes
- on finish, increment the counter to an even number
```

Reader:

```
- on start, (with a read barrier)
     - if even, take a copy of the counter.
     - if odd, retry until even.
- read the multiple values.
- read the counter again, if the counter changed, loop until it doesn't.
```

Of course if you have a single value, you just need an ordered write and a volatile read so not locking at all.

---

EDIT: I have added an example [LockingViaMMapMain](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/test/java/net/openhft/lang/io/LockingViaMMapMain.java) and [LockingViaFileLockMain](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/test/java/net/openhft/lang/io/LockingViaFileLockMain.java)  This uses two processes to lock records in a shared memory mapped files. One process locks and sets the flag to false (only if true) and the second set the flag to true (only if false)

The two processes print on my laptop

```
Toggled 10,000,128 times with an average delay of 31 ns
```

For comparison, the benchmark using FileLock looks like

```
Toggled 10,000,128 times with an average delay of 2,402 ns
```

FileLock is pretty quick, 2.4 micro-seconds, but on my machine using individual locks in the files was 80x faster.

If FileLock is fast enough you should use it because

- it doesn't alter the file.
- the lock is automatically released if the process dies.
- it should work for network mounted files systems. I wouldn't expect the internal lock to work between systems.

The interesting code reads

```
File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "lock-test.dat");
FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(tmpFile, "rw").getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, RECORDS * RECORD_SIZE);
ByteBufferBytes bytes = new ByteBufferBytes(mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()));


// the lock and toggle.
bytes.busyLockLong(recordOffset + LOCK);
try {
    boolean flag = bytes.readBoolean(recordOffset + FLAG);
    if (flag == toggleTo) {
        if (t % 100 == 0)
            System.out.println("j: " + j + " is " + flag);
        continue;
    }
    bytes.writeBoolean(recordOffset + FLAG, toggleTo);
    break;
} finally {
    bytes.unlockLong(recordOffset + LOCK);
}
```

Comment: It is good solution but in case of just two threads little bit overkill. Maybe use of ReadWrite lock would be enough. Reading could work in parallel and only writing will be blocked in case of read by another thread that is very quick.

Comment: Peter, thanks. Could you also include the case of multiple readers and writers?

Comment: Comment from Harry:Could you also elaborate on memory/read/write barriers, esp in context of Java, and then delete this 'EDIT 2' para? Based on what I know, memory barriers are needed in VERY LOW LEVEL programming to prevent instruction reordering in multi-threaded programming. However, I'm not aware if they have a use in Java.

Comment: @Harry memory barriers are needed when you built your own locking constructs. If you use synchronized and Lock these do the memory barriers for you, but there isn't anything which works between processes so you have to it yourself.

Comment: Algorithm seems to be broken. There's a chance, that reader completes before the writer performs final counter increment.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen Thank you, I was missing some details.  This should also work for multiple writers.

Comment: Peter, I'll be evaluating your solution after a few days, marking your answer as final in the meantime (as it 'feels' correct). Thanks!

Comment: Peter, I'm not a concurrency expert. But what's your opinion on Sami's comment above for simply using a `FileLock` (with may be a small API-wrapper around it)?

Comment: @Harry This is fine if you want to lock the whole file and you are not too concerned about performance.  FileLock has some advantages such as; it doesn't alter the file, if you process dies while holding the lock it is released automatically, it should work on network file systems, and the code should be cleaner.

Comment: @Harry I have added some performance numbers for FileLock as well as reasons to use FileLock.